# Require css files with require-css.js in specific order

Tags: javascript, css, requirejs, dependencies, requirecss

I have the following structure:

```
components/
----requirejs
----require-css
----flatUi
--------/css
------------flat.css
menuJSlib/
----js/
--------menu.js
----css/
--------menu.css
samples
----demo/
--------js/
------------main.js
--------css/
------------main.css
--------index.html
```

I try to load all content stuff in folder menuJSlib with requirejs and require-css in my demo project. 
In my index.html in my demo I include requirejs library.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script data-main="js/main" src="../../components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In main.js file in my demo project I have the following code:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: './../../',

  map: {
    '*': {
      'css': 'components/require-css/css'
    }
  },
  paths: {
    GameMenu: 'lib/js/menu',
    'layout': 'samples/requirejs_demo/css/main'
  }
});

require(['GameMenu', 'css!layout'], function(GameMenu) {

}
```

And the code in menu.js in my menuJSlib folder is:

```
 define('GameMenu', ['css!components/flat-ui/dist/css/flat-ui.min.css',
                        'css!lib/css/main.css'], function() {
      return GameMenu;
    });
```

How you can see the menu.js have dependencies to css files. Ok all that stuffs works fine, but the problem is that I can find a way to order the css files currectly in this case on dependencies.

[image]

As you can see, I try to make order, which get the all depends in menu.js, and next load the main.css in demo folder. In that way main.css in demo will owveride some css rules, which I needed. But the order aways follows:

```
demo/css/main.css
flatui/css/flat.css
menuJslib/css/main.css
```

I wont to make this order, without remove the css dependencies in menu.js

```
flatui/css/flat.css
menuJslib/css/main.css
demo/css/main.css
```

Is this is posible in that case?

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a solution to this problem?